# BigQuery standard sql - not match regex

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a query that will select everything
that is not matching a given regex

In legacy, we had REGEX_MATCH so I was able to do 
`WHERE x NOT REGEX_MATCH("[a-z]")`

What would be the equivalent on standard SQL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In BigQuery Standrad SQL you should use [`REGEXP_CONTAINS(value, regex)`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains) instead

For example

```
WHERE NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(x, r'[a-z]')
```